# Delete from a list while iterating

Tags: python, list

I've a list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

b = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

While traversing list `b` , if any number is less than 15, then remove its corresponding number (index) from list `a`.

For eg:- in list `b` `10,11,12,13,14` are less than 15, hence its counterpart from list `a` should be removed, ie `1,2,3,4,5`.

Currently, this is how I'm doing:

```
for index, i in enumerate(b):
    if i < 15:
        del(a[index])
```

This returns me an out of range index error.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you delete an item from a, it becomes shorter, so then the indexes don't match up. You need a different approach

Comment: I know. That's why I'm asking here :)

Comment: Note that `del` is not a function, so putting parentheses around its argument is confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use list comprehension and zip and instead of deleting elements from `a` , instead take elements in a whose `b` value is over 15. Example -

```
a[:] = [i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j >=15]
```

We are using `a[:]` on the left side, so that `a` list object gets mutated inplace. (This is different from `a = <something>` as the latter simply binds name `a` to a new list whereas former mutates the list inplace).

---

Demo -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>>
>>> b = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
>>> a[:] = [i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j >=15]
>>> a
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

When I ran it, I didn't get an index error, but I ended up producing `a` = `[2, 4, 6, 8]`. One problem could be that as soon as you start deleting elements of `a`, moving left to right, its index will shift, and will no longer align with that of `b`. I tried counting backwards instead (and I skipped on using enumerate, as I'm a noob and I find it hard to remember how it works):

```
for i in range(len(b)-1,-1,-1):
    if b[i] < 15:
        del(a[i])
```

Comment: Hahah way to game the system! While i applaud you for getting around the index error. This is still feels wrong. :thumbs_up: nonetheless!

Comment: @JavierBuzzi, Perhaps it feels wrong because its worst case complexity is quadratic

Comment: I didn't want to be mean and pick apart OPs response. Reminds me of myself when i was 15 - i would keep trying things until it worked. hahah good times

Answer (score 0):

Try using Temp list

```
  >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  >>> b = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
  >>> c=[]
  >>> for i in range(0,len(b),1):
           if b[i]>=15:
                 c.append(a[i])

  >>> a=c
  >>> a
  [6, 7, 8, 9]
```